# Get list of registered custom post types

Tags: custom-post-types

How can i get a list of all custom post types registered and show them on any template page.

I have code like this.

```
<?php

    /**
     * Template Name: Custom Post Types List
     */

    get_header();

    $args=array(
        'public'                => true,
        'exclude_from_search'   => false,
        '_builtin'              => false
    ); 

    $output = 'names'; // names or objects, note names is the default
    $operator = 'and'; // 'and' or 'or'
    $post_types = get_post_types($args,$output,$operator);

    $posttypes_array = array();

    foreach ($post_types  as $post_type ) {
        $posttypes_array[] = $post_type;
    }

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($posttypes_array);
    echo "</pre>";

    get_footer();

?>
```

Comment: Your code works fine. I just tested it. You do not have any custom post type registered which is `public` and `exclude_from_search`, that's why it's showing blank result. Try removing both of these args and see if page lists all default post types or not?

Comment: Try the codex example to make sure they are showing up at all http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_types#Examples

Answer (score 11):

Your code looks good. However, you can try the followoing codes to get all custom posts

```
    $args = array(
       'public'   => true,
       '_builtin' => false,
    );

    $output = 'names'; // names or objects, note names is the default
    $operator = 'and'; // 'and' or 'or'

    $post_types = get_post_types( $args, $output, $operator ); 

    foreach ( $post_types  as $post_type ) {

       echo '<p>' . $post_type . '</p>';
    }

    ?>
```

you can also use a bunch of args to filter your result much. For details lists of args you can check the official WordPress Codex page: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_types

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get all post types as a list you need to use the **[get_post_types](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_types)** function and loop over the results with a `foreach`.

```
<?php
    // Get All Post Types as List
    foreach ( get_post_types( '', 'names' ) as $post_type ) {
        echo '<p>'.$post_type.'</p>';
    }
?>
```

These 2 lines of code can list all of your registered post types.
If you want to know more about this **get_post_types** function visit the official wp codex page :
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_types

Answer (score 0):

```
global $wp_post_types;

$posttypes = array_keys( $wp_post_types );

// Remove _builtins or others
$pt_remove = array("attachment","nav_menu_item","customize_changeset","revision");

foreach ( $posttypes as $posttype ):

 if ( in_array($posttype, $pt_remove) ) continue;

 $posttype_names[ $posttype ] = $posttype;

endforeach;

echo "<pre>";
 print_r($posttype_names);
echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$args = array(
  'post_type'   => 'clients',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'tax_query'   => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'clients_service',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => 'therapy'
    )
  )
 );

$testimonials = new WP_Query( $args );
if( $testimonials->have_posts() ) :
?>
  <ul>
    <?php
      while( $testimonials->have_posts() ) :
        $testimonials->the_post();
        ?>
          <li><?php printf( '%1$s - %2$s', get_the_title(), get_the_content() );  ?></li>
        <?php
      endwhile;
      wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>
  </ul>
<?php
else :
  esc_html_e( 'No clients in the therapy taxonomy!', 'text-domain' );
endif;
?>
```

When the new WP_Query is called, the relevant clients are retrieved and we can loop through them. In the loop we simply output the title and the content of the client in a simple list.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct.
Your problem in the timing of executing both:

1. Registering the CPT
2. Calling the post type function you wrote.

You have one of 2 solution:

**Solution 1:**

Make sure your CPT is registered with higher priority before calling the `get_post_types` function.

**Solution 2:**

Reduce the `get_post_types` priority to start after CPT is registered.

```
add_action('init', 'your_function_name', 10);
```

I hope this help.

Thank you